# iniciar sesion en varios proyectos symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, sesiones, cuenta-usuario

Tengo desarrollado varios sistemas en Symfony 2, 3, 5 y 6.
Cuando inicio sesion en un sistema, me cierra la sesion en cualquier otro sistema, hay alguna manera de que no suceda esto y poder navegar de un sistema a otro una vez logueado.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: no se como es posible que te suceda esto pero estoy casi seguro que debe ser unproblema del stack y la configuracion de las sesiones, no deberia de pasar, pero con la poca informacion que das, solo puedo preguntarte que has intentado???

Comment: Qué tipo de autenticación usas!? cookies o JWT. En caso de usar cookies imagino tus aplicaciones sean subdominios del dominio principal, es la única manera que puedes compartir una misma cookie y así mantener la session válida para todas tus aplicaciones

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo framework.yaml de cada proyecto revisa el name de la session que no sea igual en ninguno de tus proyectos. Sino tienes name de session debes crearlo en cada proyecto y que este sea distinto.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/402124)